# Обьединение таблиц по ключевому полю в excel 2010

Tags: excel

Дорогие друзья!

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос с созданием объединенной таблицы с результатами, полученными из двух других таблиц.

В одной таблице два параметра - *ТН* и *ВО*, во второй - *ТН* и *ПП* (по несколько *ПП* для одного *ТН*).

Необходимо в третью таблицу к размноженным строкам с *ТН* и *ВО* подтянуть значение *ПП*

Буду очень благодарен за Ваши идеи и решения. Еxcel 2010, дополнительных надстроек на компьютере нет.

Спасибо.

[Ссылка на файл](http://www.excelworld.ru/_fr/436/Solution_1.xlsx)

Comment: Хоть бы пример показали нормальный. Для того, чтобы Вам помочь, надо создать книгу, нарисовать таблицы. Потом  окажется, что не там и не так...

Comment: Спасибо за правильное замечание. Приложил файл excel к вопросу.

Comment: Разве данные в рабочем файле так расположены? ТН  не меняется, всегда тройка? ПП - не больше двух? Задачу нужно описывать полнее.

Comment: Снова с Вами согласен. ТН меняется, ПП может быть сколько угодно. Файл поправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше решать макросом, но время на написание кода выходит за рамки простой помощи.

Вариант формульный. Чтобы не грузить сложными формулами массива и чтобы легче было разобраться, решение с использованием доп. вычислений.

*A3* = 1

В *A4* вспомогательная формула (определяет, в какую строку результата вносить данные `Таблицы1`):

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Таблица2[ТН];B3)+A3
```

В *K4* еще одна дополнительная формула (сцепляет *ТН* и *ВО* для корректного поиска *ПП* в `Таблице2`):

```
=Таблица3[@ТН]&Таблица3[@ВО]
```

Дальше все просто :)

ТН

```
=ВПР(СТРОКА(A1);$A$4:$C$9;2)
```

ВО

```
=ВПР(СТРОКА(A1);$A$4:$C$9;3)
```

ПП

```
=ИНДЕКС(Таблица2[ПП];ПОИСКПОЗ([@ТН];Таблица2[ТН];)+СЧЁТЕСЛИ($K$4:K4;K4)-1)
```

Все формулы  протянуть по строкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]